# jquery and html input tag

Tags: jquery

Hello everyone i am really hoping you can help me out with this,

so i have this slider and what i need to know is how to pull the information out using jquery all i need is hte name of the slider and the value it is currently set to.

```
<div class="Filter">
  <div class="FilterName">
    <p>saturation</p>
  </div>

  <div class="FilterSetting">
    <input type="range" min="-100" max="100" step="1" value="0" data-filter="saturation"        >
    <span class="FilterValue">0</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

this was my attempt at pulling the information i need out i actually found this example here on this site,

```
function displayValues()
    {
        var bright = $('#saturation').slider('value');
        alert('bright');
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help you guys give me :)

Comment: i think i may have just solved it,    
    [code]function displayValues()
    {
        var bright = $('#saturation').attr('value');
        alert(bright);
    } [/code]

Comment: where is the element with id `brightness`?

Comment: copied the wrong <input> :(

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var value = $('#brightness').val();
alert(value);
```

Working here in this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jatin146/dqmXf/

===============================

Or you can do:

```
var value = $('#brightness').attr('value');
alert(value);
```

=============================

Looks like slider() is a non existing method ... are you using any plugin?